# Run Theano on Python 3.5

Tags: windows-7-x64, theano, python-3.5

Previously I have working installation of bleeding edge Theano version on Anaconda Python 2.7 x 64 on Windows 7 x64.

I tried to upgrade to bleeding edge Theano version on Python 3.5 x64 on Windows x64 and encountered error during test example compilation:

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe -shared -g -march=ivybridge -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mno-movbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mno-abm -mno-lwp -mno-fma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mno-bmi -mno-bmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mno-avx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mno-lzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mno-clflushopt -mno-xsavec -mno-xsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=6144 -mtune=ivybridge -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof -o C:\Users\s.nechuiviter\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.1-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\s.nechuiviter\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.1-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -LC:\Anaconda3\libs -LC:\Anaconda3 -lpython35
===============================
C:\Anaconda3\libs/python35.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 75, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/GIT_MIRROR/SRP_DLA/Python_DLA/tests/theano_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import theano.tensor as T
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 22, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 12, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 646, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2204, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
.
```

How to fix this?
It seems libpython conflicts with Python 3.5?